# How to generate a repetitive namelist with loop?

Tags: loops, stata

In the example below, I need to give `svmat2` a `namelist` (in this case a list of column names). The `namelist` has a pattern -- how do I create it in a loop and then give it to the command?

```
svmat2 villagemean, names(var1_2011 var1_2012 var1_2013 ///
                          var2_2011 var2_2012 var2_2013 ///
                          var3_2011 var3_2012 var3_2013) ///
                          rnames(villageid)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a standard application of `forvalues`. See the help. There are two nested loops, over the infix `1 2 3` and over the years `2011 2012 2013`. For safety, blank out any previous contents first. Make sure you refer to this only within the space where it is created.

```
  local mylist 
  forval j = 1/3 { 
      forval y = 2011/2013 {
          local mylist `mylist' var`j'_`y' 
      }
  }
  di "`mylist'"
```

Comment: Very enlightening! Coming from other languages I keep googling about ways to "append" to a macro. Then how do I give `mylist` to `svmat2`? I tried `names(\`mylist')` and `names("\`mylist'")` without succeeding.

Comment: The first solution should work, so I guess that you did not follow the advice **Make sure you refer to this only within the space where it is created.** That means the same interactive session or program or do-file or (chunk of) do-file editor contents and the **or**s all bite; you can't cross-refer. If that doesn't illuminate the problem your experience of other languages will underline that we need to see a reproducible error.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help. Your answer solved this issue and also taught me a few things about STATA generally.

Comment: Don't Google when you can start with the [U] manual. (Standard spelling is Stata, by the way.)